# Does Enabling the Host Protected Area increase available reserved space on SATA SSD?

Tags: ssd, sata, smart

I got an old SATA SSD which is on it's last leg with regard to available reserved space.

If i perform a [SSD overprovising](https://www.thomas-krenn.com/en/wiki/SSD_Over-provisioning_using_hdparm) as described in the linked article will that increase available reserved space and replenish the 0xAA SMART statistic?

Will cutting the disk size from 120GB to 80GB by the changing host protected area as described above extend the life time of a disc which is 90% out of an available reserved space?

I already performed an [Secure Erase](https://www.thomas-krenn.com/en/wiki/Perform_a_SSD_Secure_Erase) to allow the SSD not to care about any data on it for this procedure.

Comment: "Will that extend the lifetime of a disc that is 90% out of an available reserved space?" - No; You are not going to increase the lifespan of a disk by simply increasing the reserved space by a small percentage point.

Comment: The only thing it will do is prevent fragmentation to occur when the disk runs low on space. So its not a bad thing normally, but it will not magically make the disk more robust. In fact, this operation may kill the disk.

Comment: @LPChip How does this operation may kill the disk?

Comment: If the disk is on its last legs, the operation could cause enough wear that the disk fails unexpectedly. A general rule of thumb on disks and ssd's is, when a disk is failing, every read and write will deteriorate it more.

Comment: How does sending an ATA signals which changes the controller state (which is what Enabling the Host Protected Area is supposed to do) cause wear on the disk?

Comment: @worldsmithhelper Changing the amount of reserved space requires the internal controller of the SSD to re-arrange its internal data-structures and move some (possibly a lot) of data around to other locations. That is a lot of additional writes. It is writing that wears out SSDs. Besides: You will have to reduce the the existing filesystem on the disk (if any) to be smaller than the available space remaining and that can also involve a lot of writes.

Comment: @Ramhound Assuming this 120GB SSD has around raw 128GB capacity, shouldn't going from 120GB capacity to 100GB capacity give it more breathing room then it ever had? 7% -> 20+% Can you elaborate on the math that makes you think this would only yield a small percentage improvement?